# Android Application only respond to Samsung SPen hover and touch events

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, samsung-mobile-sdk

I have an Android application that has a transparent overlay, which I want to only respond to SPen events and not regular touch input. It appears that the Pen SDK from Samsung is completely deprecated and breaks on Android 8.0 and up devices as it requires the gnustl_shared library. My original plan was to use the SDK and find the onHover and OnTouch events from the SPen. Since that is no longer an option, is there any other way I can recognize only the stylus input? In essence, I only want the touch input from the Pen to be recognized and ignore other input. I want this to work on devices with the SPen that were released before the Note 9. The new SDK for the Note 9 only allows bluetooth shutter input from clicking the pen.